# JavaCPP BytePointer OutOfMemory Error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

Sorry for bad English, not a native speaker.

I am using sourab-sharma's TouchToRecord library, available on github, I updated javacv and javacpp and now app crashes on video record with,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate 267850262 + 614403 bytes (> Pointer.maxBytes)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:446)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:118)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer.allocateArray(Native Method)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer.<init>(BytePointer.java:82)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameFilter.pushImage(FFmpegFrameFilter.java:265)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameFilter.push(FFmpegFrameFilter.java:252)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameFilter.push(FFmpegFrameFilter.java:248)
    at com.dodo.challenger.videorecorder.RecorderThread.processBytesUsingFrame(RecorderThread.java:186)
    at com.dodo.challenger.videorecorder.RecorderThread.processFramesFromList(RecorderThread.java:84)
    at com.dodo.challenger.videorecorder.RecorderThread.run(RecorderThread.java:59)
```

this. Have been working on 8 straight hours, no luck yet.

JavaCpp version was: 1.1 - now: 1.2.4,

JavaCv version was: 1.1 - now: 1.2.1

Also this message appears on error trace just in version 1.2.4, below don't have it.

```
No implementation found for long org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.physicalBytes()
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to app manifest did the trick. However for 30secs of video it used 400mbs of ram. If anyone has an answer or suggestion for it, will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixes? I have the same issue.